# ScrollView + PageControl doesn't scroll

Tags: ios, swift, scrollview

I have that code:

```
import UIKit

class ProjectsViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {
  @IBOutlet weak var pageControlBookChapters: UIPageControl!
  @IBOutlet weak var scrollViewBookChapters: UIScrollView!
  @IBOutlet weak var contentsImageView: UIImageView!
  @IBOutlet weak var contentsTextLabel: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var contentsLabel: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var projectName: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var projectImageView: UIImageView!

  var page = 0

  let arrImages : [String] = ["Captura1.jpg", "captura 2.jpg", "captura 3.jpg", "captura 4.jpg", "captura 5.jpg"];

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.createHelpView()
    pageControlBookChapters.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    pageControlBookChapters.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
    pageControlBookChapters.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor(red: 251/255, green: 108/255, blue: 108/255, alpha: 1.0)
    pageControlBookChapters.tintAdjustmentMode = UIViewTintAdjustmentMode.Dimmed
    pageControlBookChapters.numberOfPages = arrImages.count
    pageControlBookChapters.currentPage = 0

    scrollViewBookChapters.scrollEnabled = true
    scrollViewBookChapters.alwaysBounceHorizontal = true
  }

  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
  }

  func createHelpView() {

    var x = 50
    for var i=0; i<arrImages.count; i++  {
      var imgView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(CGFloat(x), 50, CGFloat(scrollViewBookChapters.frame.width-100), CGFloat(scrollViewBookChapters.frame.height-150)))
      imgView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleBottomMargin
      imgView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
      imgView.image = UIImage(named: arrImages[i])
      imgView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
      scrollViewBookChapters.addSubview(imgView)

      x = x + Int(scrollViewBookChapters.frame.width)
    }
    scrollViewBookChapters.contentSize = CGSizeMake(CGFloat(arrImages.count)*self.view.frame.width, 0)
  }

  func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    var pageWidth = CGFloat(scrollViewBookChapters.frame.width)
    var fractionalPage = scrollViewBookChapters.contentOffset.x / pageWidth
    page = lround(CDouble(fractionalPage))
    pageControlBookChapters.currentPage = page
  }
}
```

Which correctly creates the scrollview and dots of the pagecontrol, but when I try to scroll it, it doesn't move, just shows the line to scroll, but even if I click on the dot button it doesn't do anything. Is something wrong there? I have even declared the `scrollEnabled` and bounces horizontally to force it, but nothing happens. 
I have already checked the `contentSize` and seems to work properly.

Comment: You better not to set content height 0.

Comment: @trick14 Thank you for your reply. I have tried but this looks the same. If i keep my finger on the screen, and keep moving I can see a part of the next image, but not smoothly and not properly. Is something wrong there? The height should not affect, or yes?

Comment: If you can see a image of next page by `scrollView`'s bouncing, it must be a problem of content size. I think `self.view.frame.width` is not as you expected when you call this. Move `self.createHelpView()` to `viewDidAppear()` or `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` and try again.

Comment: Thank you @trick14 With viewDidAppear it worked. Can I ask you why my pageControl disappear after the first move? I mean, if you click on it, it carries you to the correct page, but when you scroll it disappears, only keep on the first view.

Comment: If you added `pageControl` to `UIScrollView`, it will happen. Add `pageControl` to `UIScrollView`'s superview.